# Artefacts when rendering multiple intersecting transparent meshes with threejs

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am trying to render a stack of transparent planes using `THREE.ShaderMaterial`:

```
const renderMaterial = new ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    color: { value: color },
  },
  vertexShader: VERTEX_SHADER,
  fragmentShader: FRAGMENT_SHADER, // fragment shader sets alpha to 0.3
  transparent: true,
  side: THREE.FrontSide
});
```

This looks fine, but as I rotate the camera around the scene, at certain angles I get rendering artefacts.

Correct render:

[image: Layered transparent meshes rendering correctly illustrated]

Corrupted render when I rotate the camera. It gets more obvious as I rotate the camera:

[image: Layered transparent meshes rendering bug problem illustrated]

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I tried experimenting with `renderer.sortObjects = false` and setting custom `renderOrder` to each transparent mesh without much success. I don't understand why it happens only at certain camera angles?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the line where you define your camera. The artefacts you're seeing are called "z-fighting" and are usually caused by a z-buffer that that is larger than necessary.

Comment: @TheJim01 here it is `this.perspectiveCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(45, this.viewportWidth / this.viewportHeight, 1, 2000);`. I suspect my far value is too big...

Comment: That depends on how far apart your layers are. If you have 5 layers, and each of them are placed only `0.1` apart along an axis, then the total depth of your layers is only `0.5` out of `2000`, or roughly 0.025% of your total depth space. You did say you're rotating, so you may need a deeper depth to account for the wide parts of your layers . But, overall, try making your `near` and `far` camera values be tighter to your layer shapes.

Comment: A second option is to try setting [`WebGLRenderer.logarithmicDepthBuffer`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer) to `true`, and then scale everything up so you have larger shapes and distances between them.